# Retrieving Blocker History from Rally

Tags: rally

Given a Rally project Id, I want to be able to browse through all the stories and the defects in the project and for each story/defect get the following information

```
Story/Defect Name,  Date blocked,   Date unblocked,     Blocked Reason
```

There doesn't seem to a webservice API to list the blockers (past and current) on a given story or defect. The only way I can think of retrieving the above information is to go through the Revision History of a story/defect and parse the revision description (BLOCKED REASON added [Random Reason], BLOCKED changed from [true] to [false]). Is there a better way to retrieve the blocker information on a story or a defect? Thanks.

The Rally webservice API I'm looking at:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historic data is available via [Lookback API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual). It is more efficient than parsing RevisionHistory object in WS API.

Each snapshot in Lookback API will have a `_PreviousValues` collection. For each snapshot, if a field has changed from the prior snapshot, then the _PreviousValues collection will be hydrated for that value.

You may try a query where:

```
'_PreviousValues.Blocked' : {$exists: true}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I wasn't aware of the Lookback API until you mentioned it, thank you.